# React Acceess Loader component from any other component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

Loader Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class Loader extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    }, 500);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span className={"loading " + (this.state.isLoading ? "show" : "hide")}>
        <span className="loading-bg"></span>{" "}
        <img src="img/loader.gif" alt="Loading" />{" "}
      </span>
    );
  }
}

export default Loader;
```

Layout Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container } from "reactstrap";
import { NavMenu } from "./NavMenu";
import Loader from "./common/Loader";
import Footer from "./Footer";

export class Layout extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavMenu />
        <Container fluid>
          <Loader />
          {this.props.children}
          <footer className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center pt-3">
            <Footer />
          </footer>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So every component will have loader and it will hide once componentDidMount()....
I want show loader when another actions like form submission and opening a modal. How to acheive it form form or modal component.

I want to reuse the same Loader component.

Answer (score 1):

the State of Loading should be in the parent components in this case it should be in the layout component and then you pass it as a prop to the Loader component.
ofcourse you should be showing the loader component of state is true and hide if false.

Comment: How to use it from another component in my case Users component. For User component I'm using Layout component as layout.

Comment: you have many solutions,
solution 1 :  to also add the state of loading in the Users component ( so you need to add that state to every component you want to show loading in )
another solution is to make a central state ( using context Api or redux ) and than access it in all components, change the state according to your condition and pass it as a prop to the Loader Component ( hope this is clear) if not try to search for Context/ Redux for state management or just stick to the first solution